# How does the demo window scrolling of jQuery's website work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

When you scroll all the way down of the page, there is a demo window. And when we scroll to the top of that demo window, and we keep scrolling even our mouse is in the demo window, the whole page scrolls. And the whole page scrolls down when we do the same thing but scrolling to the bottom of the demo window.

Can anyone explain how does this work? It would be nice if I can see an actual code. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please explain what are you trying to ask?

Comment: @progrAmmar I think he is asking when users reach the top or bottom of a scrollable are and keeps scrolling, how to scroll the entire document in that direction as in the jquery site

Comment: What to do when the scroll limit is reached is up to the web-browser. So the behaviour u described _might_ vary of different browsers. But they mostly choose to continue scrolling the next scrollable element...which in ur case is the page _document_

Answer (score 0):

Code is there itself above the demo. internally there will be executed code within html you can find those code by right click on page and inspect element.

Comment: .. and what are we supposed to do with minified production code without the map file..?

Answer (score 0):

It's not the code, it's the browser feature. When your scroll is finished on the top level and your mouse comes on a child element, it will start scrollin git after finishing scrolling it will go into the child and start scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

What to do when the scroll limit is reached is up to the **web-browser**.

So the behaviour u described *might* vary of different browsers. But they mostly choose to continue scrolling the **next** scrollable element...which in ur case is the page document.

Here is is a code and demo of it:

```
<div class="one">
  <div class="two">
    <div class="three">
      <p>xxxxxx</p>
      <p>xxxxxx</p>
      <p>xxxxxx</p>
      <p>xxxxxx</p>
      <p>xxxxxx</p>
      <p>xxxxxx</p>
      <p>xxxxxx</p>
      <p>xxxxxx</p>
      <p>xxxxxx</p>
      <p>xxxxxx</p>
    </div>
    <p>yyyyyy</p>
    <p>yyyyyy</p>
    <p>yyyyyy</p>
    <p>yyyyyy</p>
    <p>yyyyyy</p>
    <p>yyyyyy</p>
    <p>yyyyyy</p>
    <p>yyyyyy</p>
    <p>yyyyyy</p>
    <p>yyyyyy</p>
  </div>
  <p>zzzzzz</p>
  <p>zzzzzz</p>
  <p>zzzzzz</p>
  <p>zzzzzz</p>
  <p>zzzzzz</p>
  <p>zzzzzz</p>
  <p>zzzzzz</p>
  <p>zzzzzz</p>
  <p>zzzzzz</p>
  <p>zzzzzz</p>
</div>
<p>aaaaaa</p>
<p>aaaaaa</p>
<p>aaaaaa</p>
<p>aaaaaa</p>
<p>aaaaaa</p>
<p>aaaaaa</p>
<p>aaaaaa</p>
<p>aaaaaa</p>
<p>aaaaaa</p>
<p>aaaaaa</p>
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/36mknx96/)

Scroll down from the inner most element. You will notice that once the lower edge is reached, it scrolls the next scrollable parent element.

Comment: I see, it works on edge but it doesn't work on Chrome. Is there a way to force Chrome to behave like this from code?

Comment: It should be possible using JQuery functions like `element.scroll()`, `event.preventDefault()` and `element.scrollTop()`

Comment: that's what I've been trying